# Error al instalar SQL Data Sync: "please enter a valid agent key to proceed. the key must be generated from sql data sync"

Tags: sql-server, azure, windows-server, azure-sql

Instale SQL datasync agent 2.0 y cuando genero mi llave en azure y trato de conectar dice que conexcta con exito, pero al darle OK me arroja esto

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ingrese una clave de agente válida para continuar. La clave debe generarse desde el portal web SQL Data Sync

El horario de mi servidor azure es el mismo que el de mi servidor local.
saludos

Answer (score 1):

De acuerdo a la documentación el error, **la clave de agente no es válida ya que posiblemente no es la más reciente.**

Revisa en la [**documentación**](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-get-started-sql-data-sync) el siguiente paso:

3. En la computadora de SQL Server, busque y ejecute la aplicación **Client Sync Agent**.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

a. En la aplicación de agente de sincronización, seleccione Enviar clave de agente (**Submit Agent Key**). Se abre el cuadro de diálogo **Sync Metadata Database Configuration**.

b.  En el cuadro de diálogo **Sync Metadata Database Configuration**, pegue la clave del agente copiada del portal de Azure. También proporcione las credenciales existentes para el servidor de Azure SQL Database en el que se encuentra la base de datos de metadatos. (Si creó una base de datos de metadatos, esta base de datos está en el mismo servidor que la base de datos del concentrador). Seleccione Aceptar y espere a que finalice la configuración.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

---

Lo que comento lo puedes ver en el siguiente thread:

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/488ab039-03d4-49f8-bcfb-eec09327e0c3/problem-registrering-azure-data-sync-agent?forum=ssdsgetstarted

> De la excepción, parece que la clave de agente que ha ingresado no es
>   válida. La clave de agente que se envía no es la más reciente; Es
>   posible que haya regenerado una clave más nueva en el portal de Azure
>   Sync. Intente regenerar en el portal web y volver a enviar.